# Matching the text layout on the viewFlipper layout

Tags: android, xml, viewflipper

I have a viewflipper with two buttons, left and right of the view flipper.
[image]

There is text being projected on the viewflipper. When I run the emulator the text that comes on the viewFlipper pushes the two buttons out of the screen en takes the entire space.

**How can I make sure the layout of the text on the viewflipper doesn't push out the buttons and sticks within the layout of the viewFlipper?**

[image]

This is the xml layout of the viewflipper

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/promoflipper"
    android:background="@drawable/button_left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titel1" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/promoflipper"
    android:background="@drawable/button_right" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/titel1" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/promoflipper"
    style="@style/MainTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titel1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/mat" 
    >


</ViewFlipper>
```

This is the xml layout of the text on the viewflipper

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/promo_flipper"

>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/promoTitel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="@string/promoTitel"
    android:textColor="@color/listSelectorFocused2"
    android:textSize="16dip" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/promoText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@color/listSelectorPressed3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dip" />

<com.phi.android.ui.widget.AutoResizeTextView
    android:id="@+id/promoLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textColor="@color/listSelectorFocused2"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

and this is the code:

```
    LinearLayout flipLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.promo_flipper,
                    promoFlipper, false);
            TextView promoTitel = (TextView) flipLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.promoTitel);
            TextView promoText = (TextView) flipLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.promoText);

            // Make a textholder
            String text = "";
            // Get the list with this Place's Promo's
            List<Promo> promos = promoList.get(i);
            // Run through the promo's and add them to the textholder
            for (Promo promo : promos) {
                text += promo.getDescription() + "\n";
            }
            // Set the title and promo text
            promoTitel.setText(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.promoTitel)
                    + " "
                    + placeList.get(i).getName());
            promoText.setText(text);

            // Add the inflated view to the flipper
            promoFlipper.addView(flipLayout);
```

Comment: You may want to position the `ViewFlipper` with `layout_toLeft/RightOf` relative to the two buttons and not just center it in the layout.

Comment: When I do this it gives a classCastException. it works the way it is now but the text on the view flipper should stay in the layout of the view flipper. And not stretch the viewFlipper and push out the buttons.